# How to export a specific web content in Liferay?

Tags: liferay

I am using Liferay Portal 6.2CE GA3 tomcat bundle.

I have created web content and I want to export the specific web content. But there is no option to select the specific web content. I have the only option to select on date of creation range. Can any one know how to export a specific web content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the image I've uploaded.
After selecting the specific web content on the edit web content page, there is a gear icon on the right top which provides users with the export option.

[image]